# Fantasy series with a hacker/programmer wizard and female protagonist, similar to Wiz Biz

Tags: story-identification

On Goodreads I found the [Wiz Biz series](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/407212.The_Wiz_Biz):

> It all began when the wizards of the White League were under attack by their opponents of the Black League and one of their most powerful members cast a spell to bring forth a mighty wizard to aid their cause. What the spell delivered was master hacker Walter Wiz Zumwalt. The wizard who cast the spell was dead and nobody -- not the elves, not the dwarves, not even the dragons -- could figure out what the shanghaied computer nerd was good for.But spells are a lot like computer programs, and, in spite of the Wiz's unprepossessing appearance, he was going to defeat the all-powerful Black League, win the love of a beautiful red-haired witch, and prove that when it comes to spells and sorcery, nobody but nobody can beat a Silicon Valley computer geek!

I liked it. I'm not sure, but I think I saw another series, similar to *Wiz Biz*, but with a female protagonist; I can't find it or remember it at all.

Does anyone know what series that is?

Comment: How is it similar? Was she a programmer who could do magic with her programming skills? Pulled into another world without her consent? In a relationship with a beautiful redheaded witch?

Comment: I remember this! I read it on the Baen Free library. The dude didn't have the memory to be a true wizard, but he did figure out he could write and store small subroutines as building blocks. So of course like any proper hacker, the first thing he did was port Emacs to this new environment. :-)

Answer (score 6):

This series may be what you're thinking about.

[Off To Be the Wizard, Magic 2.0 book 1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00EF8Z32I)

Book 1 is primarily a male protagonist, but from book 2 on, it splits between 2 male and 2 female protagonist.

Normal people in the real world find a piece of code that lets them alter reality. The people who find this usually end up adding money to their bank accounts, alerting the IRS and so escape into the past to medieval Briton, where others who found this code have also fled. These programmers disguise themselves as wizards while they live among towns people in the 1100's.

Answer (score 4):

[*System Programmer: The Maiden and the Madman*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/44019867-system-programmer) by Jean-Philippe Janssen

> After dying, our main character found himself summoned by a young woman. She comes from a long line of summoners and had expected to partner up with a powerful being, like the rest of her family. Instead, she summoned a computer programmer, who from now on will be living inside her head. Powerless, he's unable to help her with the upcoming war. Disappointed that neither of them had been blessed by fate with some divine abilities, he decides to build a computer system inside her head himself.

Comment: Welcome to SciFi.SE! Can you explain how this matches the description?

Comment: Published in 2019, so pretty surely not the right answer, but it's a partial match.

Answer (score 2):

[Barbara Hambly's Windrose Chronicles](http://www.barbarahambly.com/hambooks.htm) has a female programmer travel to a world with magic. I didn't love it so I didn't finish it, but I seem to remember something about them using a computer program to work magic.

[JV Jones' Barbed Coil](http://jvj.com/barbedhome.html) series has a woman travel to a fantasy world, but if I remember correctly it's her artistic gifts that let her work special magic there.

Hope this helps you or somebody else that stumbles across this on google like I did.