# First fictional programming language in sci-fi or fantasy?

Tags: history-of, computers

I'm looking for the first written fictional programming language. This would exclude where a computer interprets human speech, and where we 'assume' a human is programming as they can be seen making input to a computer, but we don't see that input. References by name without code is also acceptable, so long as it's clearly a programming language.

The code needs to be run by something external to the writer, and should not just be a magic spell (which is equivalent to a computer interpreting speech).

I've found [SARTRE](https://esolangs.org/wiki/SARTRE) but that is not in a work of Sci-Fi or Fantasy. I've also found [~ATH](https://esolangs.org/wiki/%7EATH) which would count, but is only from 2018 (as far as I can tell). There is also the [computer Hex which](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hex_(Discworld)) first appears in *Soul Music* (1994) and runs on Softlore, though I don't know if it's named as such in the books, or if it first appears in that book. Druid Circles on the Discworld operate like computers, but we never see one being programmed.

Comment: The program sent in the message in "A for Andromeda"? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_for_Andromeda

Comment: @Alith possibly? Is it definitely a fictional programming language or could it be an encrypted code written in real world programming language?

Comment: I haven't read Richard Cook's "Wizardry" books since they came out (started 1989).  Anyone with a copy they can check?  The first one was in 1989 and I think I recall some programming in there, but it might have been real-life Lisp and/or Emacs Lisp rather than a fictional language.  I don't remember.

Comment: *The Moon is a Harsh Mistress* mentions LOGLAN (in a single sentence) but that [was a real language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loglan).

Comment: In the Wizardry series I know in the second book he brings in a team of programmers to create a Magic Compiler.  A programming language to make casting spells easier and somewhat automated.  "The Wizardry Compiled"

Comment: *Babel-17* (1966) mentions ALGOL and FORTRAN, and also amusingly enough, later it mentions Ruby and Python in the same sentence! But it means two dancers with those names, not the computer languages :)

Comment: I'm sure Asimov had at least one story where a computer was programmed via code and not speaking to it ... but was it a _named_ language?

Comment: @davidbak, it doesn't need a name unless we don't see a code example. Basically something to prove its fictional.

Comment: Well I don't remember any code samples in Asimov's books or stories - so I'm going for the other fork of the question ...

Comment: ~ATH was first seen some time in 2011.

Comment: @LAK, I haven't read the later books, but the first was straight puns/parodies of existing computer terminology.

Comment: Not an answer, because it was written in 2009 and is about realistic programming languages, but a really very interesting short fiction story is [Coding Machines](https://www.teamten.com/lawrence/writings/coding-machines) by Lawrence Kesteloot. I think every programmer who knows their stuff will find it incredible.

Comment: I wish that for this question, answers could be sorted by the date of the work, rather than the upvotes. It seems clear to me that Jurassic Park is getting extra upvotes just because it's got more upvotes already, and that people happening on this question are not even reading the other answers, three or four of which are just as good or better than Jurassic Park, and obviously earlier.

Comment: @RossPresser I've argued for something similar in the past, using something from code golf to accumulate the answers, but it relies on everyone conforming to an opening title.

Comment: @davidbak One of the Robots stories had the fundamental programming done by some form of keypunch, over which a visiting schoolboy ran his fingers with unfortunate effects.

Comment: @AncientSwordRage Apropos "A for Andromeda", the Wp article explicitly says that the message included a "programme". It's interesting that we've got two mentions of (Professor Sir) Fred Hoyle in this discussion, despite his relative obscurity.

Comment: @Ross Presser I've not got a copy to hand but I think the phrase was "described the changes in LOGLAN".

Comment: I think it would be helpful if you would state which of the suggested examples meet your requirements. For example, if *The Black Cloud* is a valid example of what you're looking for, then there is no need for any more entries later than 1957.

Comment: @user14111 It's boiling down to, in the earlier cases that the programmes are *very* close to existing programming languages. I'm not sure where artistic/non-scientific licence ends, and a new programming language begins.

Comment: It's your question. If you're not sure, nobody is. And if nobody knows which answers count, what's to stop this turning into a list of every fictional programming language ever written?

Comment: @user14111 it feels like this requires nuance. I don't know yet as I haven't taken the time to consider each question closely. I will make a decision when I'm able to.

Comment: @MarkMorganLloyd -- [here are the 7 matches](https://pastebin.com/Y3TbuQWP) for Loglan in my ebook copy.

Answer (score 38):

What about [Gateway](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gateway_(novel)) from 1977?

Interspersed throughout the book are excerpts from the main character's sessions with an artificially intelligent psychiatrist program (which he calls Sigfrid von Shrink), although those may be more logs than code.

An example showing the mixing of code and logs:

```
507 .IRRAY.MATURITY.GOTO             26,830
     *M80                            26,835
508 ,C, Maybe maturity is wanting    26,840
```

It goes on like this, but the line with GOTO is clearly intended to be code.

(page 44, SFBC edition)

Comment: COBOL inspired, perhaps.

Comment: In high school, we had a spirited discussion if this was a) real code, b) Robinette's thoughts at how Sigfrid was actually analyzing him, or c) just window dressing for the reader to remember that Sigfrid isn't a real person. The conclusion we came to was you have to read the code to realize that Sigfrid is truly alien (an invention of human minds using Heechee technology) and could have more motives that the code allows for.

Comment: @JesseC.Slicer That's a weird conclusion though. I thought Siegfried was just a computer artifact, basically inspired by the (abysmally bad) real-world ELIZA. That language evidently looks like nothing that would make sense. It's what an antagonistic neural network would come up when you feed it some 70's programming language and instruct it to generate something that looks alike. (Hey, that's a good CS term project). In-universe, humans don't even get the space capsule color coding, how would they connect anything to a computer system?

Comment: @DavidTonhofer well now you've given me a good reason to re-read the entire series. My recollection was that humans were pretty gung-ho to grab anything Heechee and try to integrate it (often with fatal results) and that Sigfrid was put together using some of their technology along with ours. Especially given that after Robinette "dies", his stored self (again, using Heechee "ancient ancestors" technology) happily interacts with Albert, which was created in the same vein as Sigfrid.

Comment: @JesseC.Slicer Ah, that must be in the followups. I just read Gateway II, found it notably inferior to Gateway (especially as it doesn't explain black holes correctly; you can't have a star system inside of one, and what's the deal with the alpha constant) so I dropped the "postquel".

Comment: @David Tonhofer Colour coding can be completely arbitrary, and understanding it relies on knowing how the creators' visual physiology works. OTOH a computer program can be expected to have some useful effect, and the more critical its location the more that effect can be expected to be consistent. Hence in principle, a computer program could be decoded with very little knowledge of its creators.

Comment: @MarkMorganLloyd I strongly disagree on that. Color coding is exceedingly simple to crack using basic statistical techniques because it cannot be random, so it encodes some attributes of the object denotated by the coding. A sufficiently complex computer program, however, can resist the hardest debugging efforts to pry open its intended meaning. In fact, computability theory states you may have before you something that is a "program" but no program exists that will tell you essential characteristics or even what it computes in reasonably time or even at all.

Comment: @David Tonhofer I would remind you of "Mote in God's Eye" where the Moties' eyes didn't mix blue+yellow=green. I would suggest also that much usage is cultural: red (the colour of vertebrate blood) as danger and green (the colour of a tranquil meadow) as safety and so on... creatures with greenish blood (molluscs etc.) would probably adopt a different convention.

Answer (score 37):

The earliest I can find of what I believe is a fictional programming language is in *Jurassic Park* (1990). We see Dennis Nedry's code and then Ray Arnold digging into it to find the problem. As far as I can tell it doesn't appear to have a name though and neither is it totally consistent. [This question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/135417/58193) about the language goes into a bit more detail on it and we get some snippets in it from the book, for example:

> ```
> */Jurassic Park Main Modules/
> */
> */ Call Libs
> Include: biostat.sys
> Include: sysrom.vst
> Include: net.sys
> Include: pwr.mdl
> */
> */Initialize
> SetMain [42]2002/9A{total CoreSysop %4 [vig. 7*tty]}
> if ValidMeter(mH) (**mH).MeterVis return
> Term Call 909 c.lev { void MeterVis $303 }  Random(3 #*MaxFid)
> on SetSystem(!Dn) set shp_val.obj to lim(Val{d}SumVal)
>   if SetMeter(mH) (**mH).ValdidMeter(Vdd) return
>   on SetSystem(!Telcom) set mxcpl.obj to lim(Val{pd})NextVal
> ```
>
> <sub>*Jurassic Park*</sub>

Comment: This feels like a good contender, and predates Soul Music by a good 4 year

Comment: It looks like someone looked over an early "Programming for Unix" Unix book and threw random bits of it at the screen while inventing madly.

Comment: iirc in the text it says the the OS was a custom thing that Nedry wrote as well, wasn't it? That may not mean the language itself was custom but it's close

Comment: @BinaryWorrier Even weirder since the answer in the linked question mention Crichton was a programmer too.

Comment: @martheen all programmers should know how to baffle their managers, Crichton is just exercising that ability... /s

Comment: What was the code in Sphere?  That's 1987.

Comment: *Congo* (1980) featured a programmer as well, though I don't recall if any source code appeared in the book (or if any did, if it was simple example of a real assembly language).

Comment: It's a Unix system! I know this!

Comment: Regarding my previous comment: no code in *Congo*, but the character Munro makes a passing reference (in the e-book I read, don't know how it appears in print) to "BASIC and TW/GESHUND" as two major "interactive languages" he had learned. It's not clear to me if "TW/GESHUND" is fictional or just a language I've never heard of.

Answer (score 35):

[*Valentina: Soul in Sapphire*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0671559168) (Joseph H. Delaney and Marc Stiegler, Baen Books, 1984) talks about MODULISP. Here are a few lines quoting that:

> She could write new machine language routines, of course, even though she herself was written in MODULISP, but she didn't know what to write.

> A few minutes later she was building a MODULISP kernel.
>
> Valentina put a last series of test programs through the MODULISP interpreter now downloaded onto the Looking Glass.

There's no actual MODULISP code included, but it apparently runs on a variety of platforms. "Looking Glass" in the above quote is a massively parallel architecture with thousands of optical processors.

Comment: That's very interesting, because it looks like it could be a dialect of LISP, but also seems to be a mathematical term as  well. But it having a kernel and interpreter seem to make it inarguably a programming language based on the context.

Comment: Added another quote that makes it indisputable that it's meant to be a language -- and yes, very likely a LISP dialect.

Comment: I think your "mathematical" hits on MODULISP are actually [the phrase *modulis p*](https://books.google.com/books?id=6spXAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA85&lpg=PA85&dq=%22modulisp%22&source=bl&ots=wcgWXvNc7x&sig=ACfU3U0PCx5wmGfmYV3MCN5zQI4_g8BSvA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiThKSB0K7qAhXClnIEHTW3Aa4Q6AEwAHoECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22modulisp%22&f=false), i.e. "modulo p".

Comment: Not at all. It was [published in 1984 by Baen Books](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?6656) and the authors are Joseph H. Delaney and Marc Stiegler.

Comment: Perhaps a portmanteau of [Modula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modula) and [LISP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lisp_(programming_language))?

Comment: To follow up, LISP was known as _the_ language for AI, and Modula was the most innovative, influential and first Object Oriented language. The combo-name made me laugh. Both are also famously slooow. It sounds as if "she" knows that, and is rewriting herself in machine language for speed -- isn't that what "true AI" is supposed to do?

Comment: @OwenReynolds: Modula (1977) was not object-oriented at all, and even if were, it would have been 15 years late to the object-oriented party. The first object-oriented language was Simula (1962), the most innovative and influential one probably Smalltalk-72 (still 5 years before Modula). The first member of the Wirthian family of languages, to which Modula belongs (Algol-X, Algol-W (1966), Pascal (1970), Modula (1977), Modula-2 (1978), Oberon (1987), Oberon-2 (1991), Component Pascal (1994)) with at least limited OO facilities was Oberon-2 (1991). Also, I have never heard of Modula being slow.

Comment: @Jörg W Mittag, Re "*The first member of the Wirthian family of languages [...] with at least limited OO facilities was Oberon-2 (1991).*", Turbo Pascal 5.5 had some OO features in 1989. While technically an extension to Pascal, Wirth was consulted.

Comment: @ikegami: If you include Turbo Pascal 5.5, you'd also have to include Modula-3 (1988), wich predates Turbo Pascal 5.5 by one year, and Apple's Clascal (1986). All of which still came much later than either Simula (1962), Simula II (1967), or Smalltalk-72, and even Smalltalk-80 V2.0 (1981), which is the language most people think of when they say "Smalltalk".

Comment: @JörgWMittag Ah, right, I always confuse Algol, Smalltalk, and all of those experimental languages that working programmers heard of but never used. I feel like that's the joke with Modula. You don't get the same laugh out of "algolisp" or "lispgol", or "PL/Lisp".

Comment: @owen-reynolds "never used"? Speak for yourself. I had to use a Smalltalk derivative in a work environment for several years in the 90s.

Comment: @OwenReynolds Algol and Smalltalk "experimental"? Now I have heard probably everything.

Answer (score 28):

"The Black Cloud", Fred Hoyle, 1957. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Black_Cloud

The hero (or at least the chap who consistently made the right decision) pulled an all-nighter writing an astronomical program for the Cambridge mainframe. A fragment of this is shown in the book, it was largely symbolic (but was not APL, which hadn't yet been invented) and basically comprised whatever astronomical/astrological characters the typesetter had available.

The code, on page 32 of the paperback copy, is five lines:

```
  T Z 
0 A 23 ⊖ 
1 U 11 ⊖ 
2 A 2  F 
3 U 13 ⊖
```

Described as "a short sample of the code by which the computer was instructed." [apparently this is a sample of machine code]

These symbols were transcribed to a punched strip of paper, and "the holes in the paper that constituted the final instructions to the computer."

Comment: Google books seems to partially back this up! https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=_FpXyHSNYigC&printsec=frontcover#v=snippet&q=Symbol&f=false

Comment: The code, on page 32 of my paperback copy, is five lines: "  T    Z", "0 A 23 ⊖", "1 U 11 ⊖", "2 A  2 F", "3 U 13 ⊖".

Comment: @johndoty is that input to a program or code?

Comment: @AncientSwordRage It is described as "a sample of the code by which the computer was instructed as to how it should perform its calculations and operations".

Comment: This answer seems currently the earliest, and would arguably be the best if the two quotes by @JohnDoty were to be edited in.

Comment: Many thanks to everybody who has commented. My own copy of the book is inaccessible for "interesting" reasons, and I couldn't find a scanned (as distinct from an OCRed) copy online.

Comment: It's interesting that early British computers tended towards paper tape, while American ones tended towards punched cards. I remember a "golden age" story where a spaceship was being controlled by punched cards, but there was no indication that these were any form of program... discussion elsewhere some while ago suggested that they were more likely precomputed navigation solutions.

Comment: Those 4 lines do look as if someone was trying to write hexadecimal assembly without understanding. In other words, looking "made up" may be an accident. That part may intend to educate on real computer programming, esp. since he explains the real way paper tape worked.

Comment: It wouldn't have been hex, which was rarely used in those days. However on reflection it's not entirely unlike some of the coding used for e.g. early IBM computers derived from unit record machines (punched cards etc.) where the programmer was expected to know that a character or number in a specific field had some specific effect. Again on reflection, ⊖ looks like a "nothing in this field" indicator, rather than some sort of symbolic operator. I plead that I was working entirely from memory...

Comment: It looks to me like the sort of mnemonic notation that evolved into assembly language. I'd guess that Sir Fred cribbed it from some real code. The rest of his description of the process is a very realistic depiction of mid-50's computing. The Adams-Leverrier method is a real thing. The intermediate results printed from the output tape are a bit hard to read because they're formatted to be used as input to another program. The "valves" (or vacuum tubes, in different dialect) keep the computer room cozy in January.

Comment: **This is not fictional.**  The novel describes the real Cambridge Mathematical Laboratory, which indeed was in a building that used to be the Anatomy School as the novel says.  The computer is EDSAC, which was indeed programmed via paper tape, and *that is what its programming language looks like*.  https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/events/EDSAC99/history.html https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/events/EDSAC99/simulators/echo/flat.html

Comment: I'll bite :-) Is that demonstrably EDSAC code, including the special character?

Comment: The "special character" is _theta_.  Read the character codes section of what I pointed to.

Comment: @JdeBP I'm not certain. It looks the same, but I don't see a reference to  ⊖ in either link. I need to give it some thought

Comment: Then you haven't read the character codes section, as I said to read.  Or you could read one of Fred Hoyle's biographies, or even J. M. Wheeler's 1992 IEEE paper.  The fact that the computer in the novel is EDSAC, and its description is accurate, is not a secret nor a recent discovery by me.  (-:

Comment: @JdeBP I can assure you that I find the EDSAC connection interesting. I've worked with far more people associated with the early Manchester (or various American) computers than the Cambridge ones.

Answer (score 18):

Programming a computer is often mentioned in (Science) Fiction but rarely any details are given.
It usually isn’t needed for the story itself. And many authors themselves had only a vague idea how ‘programming’ worked. Even if they did know most would realize the vast majority of their reading public wouldn’t know anything about it, so why bother?

I’m not sure if this qualifies by your restrictions, but I offer it anyway:
The Voyage of the Space Beagle by A.E. Van Vogt is from 1950.
It makes reference to ‘Symbolic Logic’ as a tool for structuring information and entering it in computers for automatic processing. It is maybe not a programming language by itself, but if I recall the novel correctly, its usage is vague enough that it could actually be the name of the programming language.

EDIT: I just discovered that the Symbolic Logic and Nexialism concepts by A.E. van Vogt are actually older. "The Voyage of the Space Beagle" is a re-work/expansion of his own short story "Black Destroyer" from 1938. The concepts where already in that short story.

Comment: Symbolic Logic may just be an old-timey way of describing a 'Programming Language' or 'Boolean Logic'. I did however find this: http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?2687890 which is listed as 'non-fiction'

Comment: @AncientSwordRage It is most definitely NOT a synonym for Boolean logic in the book.

Comment: I recall that Psychology and Sociology were sciences in that future, with a mathematical basis. The main character was an expert in that new field, sent as the ship's "morale officer". I assume Symbolic Logic was something to do with that.

Comment: The "Symbolic Logic" in the book is almost certainly [symbolic logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_logic#Symbolic_logic), which is very much not fictional.

Comment: @Mark I think you're right. van Vogt was really interested in this sort of thing and based several of his novels on various logic systems (e.g. the NULL-A books). Voyage is actually a rework of his own (his first work) short story "Black Destroyer" from 1938 which is a few year after Gödels initial works (1929 and 1931) on Symbolic Logic.

Comment: I agree with t'other Mark. There was also mention of symbolic logic in (the first of?) Asimov's Foundation books, but it was made very clear that it was being used to encode and analyse a sequence of diplomatic statements (and demonstrated that in practice they cancelled out hence conveyed no useful message).

Comment: @MarkMorganLloyd I had forgotten about Foundation, but now you mention it... This analysis for meaningful content is used by van Vogt too. Foundation is later than Black Destroyer, but predates Voyage.

Comment: IIRC "Voyage of the Space Beagle" has some sort of synthesiser-like musical instrument used to program people... does it count? :-)

Comment: @MarkMorganLloyd I reread Voyage just last year. Not really an instrument as I recall. More like a ambient sound generator that would "open" susceptible people to hypnosis. The real hypnosis came later. The ambient sound had various levels of success. Most people would not consciously hear it, just become susceptible. Some woudl need a slight adjustment to the sound before it came really effectively. On others it just wouldn't work at all. (Or require a special session with the sound fine-tuned specially to that person.)

Answer (score 9):

As @LAK said in a comment that I noticed after I got the book from my library, in the 1989 book "The Wiz Biz" by Rick Cook, Wiz created a forth-like language to execute magical instructions to create spells. This is not "magic interpreting spoken word" but invoking a formal programming language verbally (maybe some writing, it has been a while) that Wiz developed and modifies.

http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/407212.The_Wiz_Biz

See also this question:  [Fantasy series with a hacker/programmer wizard and female protagonist, similar to Wiz Biz](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/120304/fantasy-series-with-a-hacker-programmer-wizard-and-female-protagonist-similar-t) which describes other books with similar magical computer languages.

The source code is not shown (as far as I could see with a flip through the book) but is described as "a mixture of runes, numbers, and mathematical symbols appear[ing] in glowing green fire" (though might have been the object code which the forth-like language compiled to), but here are a few examples of the API (commands) that Wiz issues:

```
"class drone grep moria"
"$" said the Emac...
"exe," Wiz said...
```

Comment: I am so glad you guys mentioned this series, I read it as a kid and totally forgot about it, but enjoyed it a lot. Now to see if I can scrounge them up....

Comment: @dwllama - If you have a copy, can you give code examples?

Comment: @Malady: No source code shown as far as I could see, see answer for a description.

Answer (score 7):

I don't know if it can be considered on topic, but at the beginning and ending of [Edward Wellen "No other gods"](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/41733920-no-other-gods) (1972) are listed some lines of a fictional code.
The language is never named, but may be named "QOGIC", since that appears in a REMARKS section on the first page (see below). The language looks almost exactly like COBOL, except that the line numbers begin with the letter Q.

```
Q01010 IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.  
Q01040 PROGRAM-ID. 'END RUN.'  
Q01060 AUTHOR. COMPUTER.  
Q01080 INSTALLATION. COMMUNICATIONS CENTER AT GALACTIC HUB.  
Q01100 DATE-WRITTEN. YESTERDAY.
Q01120 DATE-COMPILED. TODAY.
Q01140 SECURITY. CLASSIFIED.
Q01160 REMARKS.
Q01161 THIS QOGIC PROGRAM IS FOR THE ESTABLISHING OF TOTAL
Q01162 ENTROPY.
```

Here it is on [Google Books](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_21st_Golden_Age_of_Science_Fiction_M/Gv5PCgAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=Edward+Wellen+%22No+other+gods%22&pg=PA217&printsec=frontcover).

Comment: That looks like COBOL to me (based on one mandatory course I took some 35 years ago).

Comment: I don't think that COBOL line numbers start with a 'Q' and I believe other languages may have used a similar number system.  But as this work is published 15 years after a plausable answer that is posted prior to this answer, I am not sure this answer adds value

Comment: @JamesJenkins Honorable mentions are generally welcomed as answers on SFF.SE

Answer (score 3):

Probably not the first one, but the most advanced (or useful) is Furor. It's an interpreted scripting programming language developed by Viola Zoltán (in eastern name order), also known as Poliverzum and Harold King or Fossil Codeger. Its purpose is to be used (royalty-free) in his new Sci-Fi novels as an esoteric language by some galactic empire (I've only read a fantasy book from him "Kajjám, a Tévedés", so I don't know more about his Sci-Fi books, however I liked that one).

The language itself is Turing-complete, has a weird syntax, and the author promised to open its source code once it's complete. He released a preliminary binary interpreter for Linux (hosted by someone else), that can be downloaded from [here](http://falu.me/20200420/fura-furabb-legfurabb-furor) (check the .tar.bz2 file).

He's Hungarian, I've read the aforementioned book in Hungarian, but he moved to the US, and writes his new books in English.

Comment: The question is looking for the earliest, please only answer if you think it is the earliest else this isn't really an answer and more of a comment.

Comment: Since OP didn't define how the "first fictional programming language" is meant. AFAIK it's the first one that is actually a working programming language with an interpreter that runs it, not just some garbage a Sci-Fi writer made up and looks like code.

Comment: Given Hex from the Discworld is given as an example in the question, I'm pretty sure that 'working in the real world' was not required.

Comment: Interestingly, by creating a complete programming language for their Sci-Fi stories, that could disqualify itself as fictional programming language.

Comment: Well, Elvish and Klingon were created for art. Are they fictional languages? Technically they exist, so they aren't. Also, by creating a language and naming it after the winner, you could disqualify any fictional programming language.

Comment: I would included "created for fiction" as "fictional". But do we see the code in the story, or is it mentioned by name? Because that is more what counts.

Answer (score 2):

@RossPresser mentioned Samuel Delaney's "Babel-17" (1966) already, but only to note that  the real-life languages ALGOL and FORTRAN appear in the text.  Somehow he missed mentioning that Babel-17 is *itself* the name of a fictional language. It is initially presented in the story as being a natural language that the protagonist must learn, but in a major plot point is later revealed to be a programming language. Now arguably it doesn't fit because the, er, 'machines' being programmed are not mechanical but are other sentient creatures. But it does meet fit the requirement that a human can compose a program in Babel-17 that is run elsewhere, specifically in the brain of a target adversary.

Comment: Thank you, I hadn't thought about that one.

Answer (score 1):

#### 1983, Superman III

[Superman III (DenOfGeek article includes screen caps and discussion of exactly this topic)](https://www.denofgeek.com/movies/what-superman-3-teaches-us-about-computer-programming/?amp) features Gus Gorman doing some coding.

Whilst it is clearly some variation on BASIC or LISP, equally clearly it does not make functional sense in any known language and therefore by definition is a fictitious language. (In-universe anyway; out-of-universe we know it's just something put together to fill a screen convincingly enough for a couple of seconds of film, of course.) The language itself is not named in the film, but in-universe it exists, apparently works, and can be seen being entered.

Comment: Doe you have any screen caps? I can only remember the kryptonite scene where he types human language in and the computer interprets it.

Comment: @AncientSwordRage The DenOfGeek link includes some screen caps from Gorman's training session at the start of the film. I've edited my answer to make this clearer.

Comment: I think even the article implies it's BASIC, unless I've misread it?

Comment: The program-within-a-program is missing `FOR`s and `LET`s, so at best it is `Syntax error in 10`.

Comment: That's just BASIC on the screen. Funny thing is that it's mostly PRINT statements which are printing... more BASIC! Leaves me to wonder if it was prepared as a sort of production in-joke.

Answer (score 0):

This is for consideration since I don't think it fully matches OP's criteria. In "The Lost Worlds of 2001" (1972) one of the draft scripts describes one of the astronauts spending some hours modifying and testing the ship's computer's program to allow him to take one of the pods out, despite none of the others being conscious. The programming language is unnamed, no example is given, and the draft was unpublished.

In one of the sequels, HAL's architecture is described in terms which make it sound like some sort of dataflow machine, with the possibility of "memories in transit" being overlooked by the remedy which removed Hal's psychoses.

Separately, in Imperial Earth (1975) I think there was an example of "if this happens then do that" programming of the protagonist's PDA. Again, I don't have my copy to hand so can't check.

Comment: For Imperial Earth, did you mean this passage? "There was no # or `EXECUTE` sign at the end of the sequences, but that proved nothing at all, for few people bothered to write down anything so obvious; nine times out of ten, it was omitted as understood. Yet one of the standard ways of canceling a secret `ERASE` order was to hit `EXECUTE` twice in quick succession. Another was to do so with a definite interval between the two keyings. Did Karl’s omission have any significance, or was he merely following the usual convention?"

Comment: Quite possibly, but you'll have to excuse my being vague: my copy's inaccessible (which doesn't stop it from being one of my favourite Clarke books).

Answer (score -1):

ICE, from Burning Chrome (1982). ICE stands for Intrusion Counter-measures Electronics. While it's called electronics, the way it's used in the book clearly depicts it as a programming language. This makes sense in the context of the computers that existed at the time, which would often be hard-coded logical circuits used to accomplish specific tasks, such as bank account management and simulations of newtonian movement; in other words, the circuit to accomplish the program *was* the program. While no name is given to the language(s) the characters actually write in, the book makes it clear that the visuals present in the character's hallucinations are programs created in ICE.

All right, there seems to be some confusion about what a programming language is. I take a very broad view; a programming language is a computer program that provides an abstraction of a logical circuit. Note that it isn't what "creates" a computer program; it creates an abstraction for the logic behind the program. If you wanted to, you could directly construct any computer program you liked out of AND gates, OR gates, and a storage buffer of some kind, and it's never a programming language that does the actual construction of the program anyway; it only serves as the rules for construction. Programming languages do us the kindness of abstracting the idea of a certain combination of those gates into something that makes more sense for humans. Under the header of what I consider a programming language includes Verilog, C, Python, Powerpoint, Minecraft, and the fictional ICE, which is clearly the abstraction of the logic for defense programs in the world of Burning Chrome and Neuromancer.

Okay, I've been downvoted to the pits of stackexchange hell, and apparently no one else seems to think that ICE is a programming language. Instead of deleting the post, I'm just going to see how far we can dig this hole:

- ICE isn't a programming language, it's a class of software!

So are IDE's. And so are word processors, spreadsheet applications, and the many games that include functions that allow the user to create and run programs within the game, which I also consider programming languages in and of themselves, as they create a different abstraction from other languages of their underlying logic. ICE obviously represents the underlying logic of the defense systems in the world of Burning Chrome, and can be modified on-the-fly by the main characters as they work towards their goal.

- Programming languages must be written!

See: Scratch, Minecraft, Powerpoint

The idea that a language must be written might also be seen as somewhat offensive by those that speak primarily in a gesture-based language such as ASL, and comes across as just a little tone-deaf considering many of the large number of languages currently on the brink of extinction are unwritten - https://www.nytimes.com/1991/12/31/science/in-a-publishing-coup-books-in-unwritten-languages.html

- Neuromancer came before Burning Chrome!

Yes, and, no. Burning Chrome the short story was released 1982, Neuromancer was released 1984, and Burning Chrome the short story compilation was released 1986. See https://omnimagazine.com/taking-agency/

Comment: ICE seems to be a _program_ and not a programming language. Like a mean firewall. In the last 1/2 of your answer you even say that: "while no name is given...". The stuff about dedicated electronics -- it's Sci Fi, so maybe Mr. Gibson was thinking that, but probably not. For real, late 1970's had special banking computers, but were still programmed.

Comment: You have to read the story to understand what I mean here. Gibson never describes "an ICE" when talking about the visual abstractions in his book; he says "walls of ICE," "the halls of Chrome's ICE," "castle of ICE," "her most sophisticated ICE is structured to fend off warrants." The usage of ICE in context of the phrases the author uses makes it clear that ICE is what much of the logical structures in the story's universe are constructed from, which is something that we would now call a programming language. All I said was that Gibson never named his counter-ICE language.

Comment: His later book, Neuromancer expands on ICE, decks, cyberspace... and it's famous. You'll find many descriptions of ICE _as a security program_. As far as walls of ice, jacked-in hackers see cyberspace as a virtual world -- a wall of ICE is somewhat like a minecraft wall of RedStone.

Comment: There's not enough room in these comment sections to go through a whole explanation of my thought process here, so I think that we'll have to agree to respectfully disagree on this point. I have read Neuromancer, and it was that book, in fact, that better describes ICE as a language, at least in my opinion. Burning Chrome was just the first occurrence of ICE, and so more relevant to this discussion.

Comment: ICE is clearly *programmed*, sure - but it isn't a language. It's a construct which does something. Somewhere, some programming has happened and the ICE is the end result, but it is a *thing* and not a language. The play Macbeth is constructed from English words, but that doesn't make the play a language. And no, Gibson never describes the process of coding except in the most general sense.

Comment: All right, I've clarified my answer. Hopefully this clears some things up.

Comment: I don't think this meets the definition of a language, which requires writing.

Comment: *Burning Chrome* is **NOT** earlier than *Neuromancer*.

Comment: And ICE is not a language, nor a specific program. It's a *class* of software, like "word processor" or "spreadsheet software".

Comment: Yes, Burning Chrome was released before Neuromancer (https://omnimagazine.com/taking-agency/). You're thinking of the 1986 short story volume of the same name. And there doesn't have to be a difference between a class of software and a programming language. As I mentioned, many video games and word processors have features that allow the user to program at a high level, and so can be referred to as programming languages within my definition of the term.

Comment: @odd135 Sorry, didn't know about the earlier short story.  I suppose you're not entirely wrong about what you say about individual scriptable programs, but you haven't convinced me, at least, that ICE qualifies. It's too broad of a category. One can talk about VBA, the language (previously) used by MS Office programs, without calling MS Office a programming language. I don't think you're going to convince most other readers of this question either, and that's why your answer has been seriously downvoted. (Though not by me.)

Comment: @odd135 "Programming languages must be written!" I don't think it's necessary to plumb^H^H^H^H^H scale the heights of political correctness to discuss this. OP said that it shouldn't simply be a spoken set of instructions and the implication was that it should be entered via some form of terminal; I suggest that since APL is a bona-fide computer language and since I believe there is a Russian programming language using Cyrillic, then it would also be fair to consider computer languages based on Arabic or Chinese characters hence that high level descriptions like Scratch are entirely fair game.